# How to show directly the symmetry of the quantum state fidelity?

Tags: quantum-information, symmetry, density-operator, quantum-states

Consider the [quantum state fidelity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fidelity_of_quantum_states) $F(\rho,\sigma)$ defined as (I will use the notation used in Nielsen & Chuang here):
$$
F(\rho,\sigma) \equiv
\operatorname{Tr}\sqrt{\rho^{1/2}\sigma\rho^{1/2}} =
\operatorname{Tr}\lvert\sqrt\sigma\sqrt\rho\rvert.
$$
It is a standard result that this function is symmetric: $F(\rho,\sigma)=F(\sigma,\rho)$.

This is straightforwardly seen through Uhlmann's theorem or the representation of the fidelity as maximum over all possible POVMS of the  fidelity of the associated probability distributions:
$$F(\rho,\sigma) = 
\max\lvert\langle\psi_\rho\rvert\psi_\sigma\rangle\rvert
$$
when maximising over all possible purifications of $\rho$ and $\sigma$, and
$$
F(\rho,\sigma) = \min F(p_m, q_m)
$$
when minimising over all possible POVMs $\{E_m\}_m$ and
$p_k=\operatorname{Tr}(E_k \rho)$ and $q_k=\operatorname{Tr}(E_k \sigma)$.

However, the way these results are obtained does not make it very clear to me why $F(\rho,\sigma)$ should be symmetric.
It seems weird that one would need to study an enlarged space, like is the case when passing through Uhlmann's theorem, to only show the symmetry of $F$.
On the other hand, to show
$F(\rho,\sigma) = \min F(p_m, q_m)$
one requires a few manipulations that make it a bit obscure to me how similar ideas could be used to prove the simpler result of the symmetry of $F$.

Is there a simpler, more direct way to prove that the fidelity is symmetric?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows directly from the fact that the trace norm is symmetric, $\mathrm{tr}\,|X|=\mathrm{tr}\,|X^\dagger|$.